# RecyclerView in fragment leaking parent Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

In my app i have a MainActivity with a ViewPage consisting in 3 fragments. Two of thse Fragments have a RecyclerView Populated by some CardView. Everything is working fine but after Installing canary leaks i noticed that my RecyclerViews are leaking the MainActivity:[image: , the last 3 lines of CanaryLeaks look like this :]

It looks like there should be static reference that prevents GC from doing his job but there is no such thing in my code. I've tried calling

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(null) or recyclerView.cleanup()
```

on my Fragment's onDestroy/onDestroyView but the leak is still there

This is my Fragment :

```
 @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {     

   //here some FirebaseDatabasereference

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_fragment_layout, container,false);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    return recyclerView;

} 

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Event, MyEventViewHolder>(

            Event.class,
            R.layout.event_card,
            MyEventViewHolder.class,
            myDatabase.child("Events").orderByChild(ordering[orderingSelector]),

    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final MyEventViewHolder viewHolder, final Event model, final int position) {
        final String post_key = getRef(position).getKey();

            viewHolder.setEventName(model.getEventName());
            viewHolder.setEventImage(getApplicationContext(),model.getEventImagePath());

            ValueEventListener likeCheckerListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.child(post_key).hasChild(currentUser.getUid())){
                        viewHolder.setThumbDown();
                        mDatabaseLike.removeEventListener(this);
                    }else{
                        viewHolder.setThumbUp();
                        mDatabaseLike.removeEventListener(this);
                    }
                    mDatabaseLike.removeEventListener(this);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            };
            mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(likeCheckerListener);

recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}

 @Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
}
```

and this is my ViewHolder :

```
public class MyEventViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

View mView;
CircularImageView cardProfile;
TextView cardLikes,cardDate,cardTime;
TextView event_name,joiners,etaMedia,maleSex,cardPrice,femaleSex;
FABRevealLayout mFABRevealLayout;
Button chiudi;
FloatingActionButton fabLike;



public MyEventViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    mView=itemView;


    //removed some UI declaration and methods for readability
    cardTime = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.cardTime);

    fabLike = (FloatingActionButton)mView.findViewById(R.id.fabLike);

}


public void setThumbUp (){
    fabLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_star_empty_24);
}
public void setThumbDown (){
    fabLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_star_full_24);
}
```

I don't know if this could be usefull but the leaks is usually from 14KB to a max of 50KB. I've been able to solve every other leak but this one is driving my crazy

Comment: You may also call `recyclerAdapter.cleanup()` in onDestroy. This issue looks similar to : https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/244, but In your case `recyclerView.setAdapter(null)` does not help.

Comment: Thanks this apparently worked by calling recyclerAdapter.cleanup() in @onDestroyView

Answer (score 0):

Is your recyclerView static ?
Anyway you should set recyclerView to null (`recyclerView = null`)in onDestroyView (As it is initialized in onCreateView).

Comment: My recyclerView is not static, i've tried calling recyclerView.setAdapter(null) respectively in onDestoy, onDestroView and onStop() with not success

Comment: You should set recyclerView = null and  adapter firebaseRecyclerAdapter = null.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the following call:

```
mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(likeCheckerListener);
```

you could simply comment it and see if leak is still happening.

Your likeCheckerListener is an Object of an Anonymous class, which has a reference to the Anonymous class created by overriding FirebaseRecyclerAdapter which has a reference to your activity. This causes the leak.

In order to be able to safely handle this scenario you should maintain a reference for EVERY ValueEventListener added to your mDatabase and remove them all in your onStop/onDestroy methods.

For this probably you should maintain a map with your listeners and the key where they are listening.

Also consider override the onViewRecycled() method of the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and then you also can remove the listeners one by one when views are recycled and only listen for events on items which are actually needed.

Comment: my likeCheckerListener gets removed with ref.removeListener(this) in the dataSnapshot block, as i commented above the solution was to call setAdapter(null) AND cleanup()

Comment: yes you are right. I am not sure why I didn't see that ;)